# Why IsWindowVisible makes callback of EnumDesktopWindows runs only once?

Tags: windows, winapi

See the following code.

The MyEnumProc runs only one time with the following code. But if I commented out the IsWindowVisible(wnd);, it runs many times.

Why IsWindowVisible make this happened(run only one time)? I thought IsWindowVisible just a function to check the wnd's attributes?

codes of test.c:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
BOOL CALLBACK MyEnumProc( HWND wnd, LPARAM lParam )
{
    printf("run\n");
    IsWindowVisible(wnd);
}

int main( void )
{
    EnumDesktopWindows( NULL, MyEnumProc, 0 );
    printf("end\n");
    return 0;
}
```

My environment is:

Windows XP SP3.

gcc 3.4.6(mingw)

compiled option is: gcc -o test.exe test.c

I did the compile and run the test.exe in the cmd.exe.

Comment: I know that you are new here, but please remember to accept one of your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EnumDesktopWindows expects you to return a value from your MyEnumProc:

```
return TRUE;
```

Read the documentation for more information.

Comment: The winapi is so bad - it should not different with/without IsWindowVisible(). If it require a return, then should always require.

Comment: @Chen Win API is fine. How can you blame the Win API for your failure to return a value from a function? That's a very basic programming error. Just because you don't know Win API, doesn't make it bad.

Comment: I think the api should work consistently. It should always fail if I return nothing. Now if I comment out the IsWindowVisible, it see the return value as TRUE.

Comment: Why the IsWindowVisible affect the return value? it should not. and even more, if I add something like printf, the behavior changed. so if I have both IsWindowVisible and printf, it works even I don't have a return.

Comment: @Chen The calling code is looking at a register / bit of memory and assuming that whatever data is there is the return value. Since you failed to specify a return value, that register / memory is filled with leftover data from your earlier calls.

Comment: @Chen The effect you are talking about is nothing to do with Windows API, it's the C++ language. Not returning a value from a function results in undefined behaviour. So your program is at fault rather than the API.

Comment: @Chen The return value is passed through the EAX register. When you call the IsWindowVisible function, that sets the EAX register for its return value, which you happen to ignore. That then gets returned from your callback. Presumably the window being enumerated is visible which is why TRUE is returned. When you comment out IsWindowVisible then you get whatever happens to be in the EAX register and I guess it happens to be 0 which means FALSE.

Answer (score 3):

You have to return a value. I would expect your compiler to be warning you that you are not. If it is not warning you then you should change the options to make it do so.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633498%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) states:

> To continue enumeration, the callback
>   function must return TRUE; to stop
>   enumeration, it must return FALSE.

This capability to terminate enumeration exists to allow you to short-circuit an enumeration. Once you have found the item you want there is no need to continue receiving callbacks. There are numerous Windows API functions that follow this idiom.

Comment: The compiler did not give me a warning.

Comment: @Chen I urgently recommend that you configure it to do so. In fact I'd configure it to make it an error rather than a warning.

Comment: Yeah, I should. But I actually not a windows programmer, I just need to write a small windows program today. I mean, I am not so similar with this windows building environment. but thanks, I will try to configure the compiler to be more strict.

Comment: @Chen to do what David suggest yo have to add two option to your compiler invocation: -Wall -Werror