# How can I check if a process has a graphical interface (without .NET)?

Tags: c++, python, windows, ctypes

I'm trying to understand which processes has the graphical interfaces. I was trying to use [GetGuiResources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683192%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but some of the processes have GUI resources but don't have the window. Now I use [WaitForInputIdle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687022%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - the same, some of the processes ready for input, but they don't have the window :(. How can I check if a process has a graphical interface?

P.S. I use Python + ctypes, but example on C++ or small explanation what should I use will be enough :)

Comment: What is your actual goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your target is Windows you can use Win32 API. **EnumWindows** function enumerates child windows, or alternatively you can use **EnumThreadWindows** to enumerate only the non-child windows.

I hope this can give you some help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. EnumWindows returns a lot of handles. I need to associate each handle with current process, yes? EnumThreadWindows - I should get all threads and then check every thread using EnumThreadWindows, yes?

Comment: **EnumThreadWindows** needs the threadId associated with the Window.  
You could use **EnumDesktopWindows** function once you want only the UI processes. See if it fits in your solution.  
[Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251247/why-iswindowvisible-makes-callback-of-enumdesktopwindows-runs-only-once)  
Do not forget to return the TRUE or FALSE in your callback :)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Now it works. I extract all threads from process, then use EnumThreadWindows for extracting window's handles from each thread and then I check if windows are visible (IsWindowVisible).